# I can not make a query with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Good morning I am having a trouble while trying to create a simple query with Eloquent.

This is mi colonia model:

```php
class Colonia extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'catalogo_colonias';   

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\City', 'ciudades_id');
    }
}
```

if I do.

```php
$response = Colonia::find(1)->city;
```

I am getting a response but i do not want to find by id, I am trying to make something like this.

```php
$response = Colonia::where('codigo_postal', $codigo_postal)->city;
```

but it throws me an error.

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$city

and it is declared above as you can see, I guess that is a syntax problem, hope you could help me.

Thank you, greetings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```php
$response = Colonia::find(1)->city;
```

The `find()` method will return the result of the query, in this case the first object of the `catalogo_colonias` table. A single object, this object has all your defined properties, like the `city` relation.

Now, when you use the [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses) method instead, this still hasn't retrieve the relationship objects yet because in some cases you would want to keep constraining the query. Instead, it returns an instance of the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html) class. That's why it throws an error:

```php
$response = Colonia::where('codigo_postal', $codigo_postal) // return query builder
                 ->city; // this property isn't defined in the builder, hence, the error.
```

To get the result you need to append the `get()` (to get all the results that matches the query) or the `first()` or etc.

```php
$response = Colonia::where('codigo_postal', $codigo_postal) // query builder
                 ->first() // returns an instance of Colonia
                 ->city; // now it can access the model properties.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help.

Comment: @MexaFireg glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that the `Colonia::where()` returns the query builder. You need to extract it, using the method `first()`, like:

```php
$response = Colonia::where('codigo_postal', $codigo_postal)->first()->city;
```

You can extract the info from the query with two methods: `first()` and `get()`. The `first()` returns only the first element found, and the `get()` returns an array with the whole results.

I recommend you to read the [Laravel Query Builder - Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. It's easy fix. You have specified the column you would like to search against. But Eloquent hasn't really executed your query.

If you use `Model::where('col', $value')` you have to specify:

1. Would you like to return one Model row? If so you can use `first()` p.s. it will return the first one it finds, so if you're trying to find a name with Bob, and you have records `Bob1, Bob2, Bob3` it will return `Bob1` first.
2. Would you like to return all rows thats within your query, you can use `get()`. You will have to `foreach` your collection to access the realtionship on each instance.

Then you can access your relationship property.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @HCK has explained how to execute the results of query. Here I just want to improve way to return the value of the column directly.

```
$response = Colonia::where('codigo_postal', $codigo_postal)
    ->value('city');
```

[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#retrieving-results)